# In Python how to add a semicolon at the end of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write this dictionary to a file, but i want a semicolon at the end of each keys.
For instance:

```
Cricket = {
    'CricketSport {': {
        'Bat': "White;",
        'Ball': "Red;",
        'Wickets': random.choice(range(1, 3)),
            }
        }
```

The desired output I want is

```
CricketSport {
Bat:White;
Ball:Red;
Wickets:2;# I want this semicolon after the number 2
}
```

Have tried to use .append(";") but didnt work. Any help is appreciable, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you try write is some custom format, i.e. it's not dict written to file. Why not simply construct proper string and write it? Why the whole dict hassle?

Comment: I am really curious how you write this `Cricket` thing/dict to file and getting the shown output (even without last semi-colon).

Comment: If dict is supposed to be written to a file, then the final output is incorrect: it misses commas afer dict entry.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, exactly my point, also the colon after `CricketSport` is missing and 2 curly braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
'Wickets': f'{random.choice(range(1, 3))};',
```

Comment: IMHO, this is very much XY problem. OP goal is to write in the file some custom format and I don't know why the whole dict non-sense, instead of creating proper string

Comment: @Barmar Oh Damn, That was easy, should have figured out by myself!! Shouldnt have come to Stackoverflow for this!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are serializing an object, you'd likely need to write your own method.

```
def dump_as_is(obj):
    def walk():
        for k, m in obj.items():
            yield k

            for nk, nv in m.items():
                if not isinstance(nv, str):
                    yield f'  {nk}:{nv};' 
                else:
                    yield f'  {nk}:{nv}'

        yield '}'

    return '\n'.join(walk())
print(dump_as_is(Cricket))
```

also, you may want to rewrite it with a clear definition

```
cricket = {
    'CricketSport': {
        'Bat': "White",
        'Ball': "Red",
        'Wickets': random.choice(range(1, 3)),
    }
}

def dump(obj):
    def walk():
        for k, m in obj.items():
            yield k

            for nk, nv in m.items():
                yield f'  {nk}:{nv};'

        yield '}'

    return '\n'.join(walk())

print(dump(cricket))
```

which will give

```
CricketSport
  Bat:White;
  Ball:Red;
  Wickets:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use String interpolation. for example using the print function:
`variable = "blah blah text" print(f"{variable};")`

> OUTPUT:
> blah blah test;